# Show a React Skeleton Loader until a image load completely

Tags: reactjs

I Have a `react-loading-skeleton` in my component, i have a static image in my page that i loaded using img tag, i want to show a skeleton component until the image loads.
I tried react.lazy and suspense but it only shows until the component load not works until image loads completely.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class SlideItems extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={require("./someImg.jpg")}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Start by adding constructor and state to class:

```
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
      image: '',
     }
    }
```

You can then add `onLoad` property to image tag like this:

```
<img src={require("./someImg.jpg")} onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}/>
```

And create function that handles image loading:

```
handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ image: 'loaded' });
}
```

Then in render you can do something like this:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   {!this.state.image &&
    <SkeletonComponent/>
   }
   <img src={require("./someImg.jpg")} onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: I added a height of 0 while loading to hide image.

<img
    src={require("./someImg.jpg")}
    height={this.state.image ? '60%' : '0'}
    onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
/>